# Starting PostgreSQL server after a HDD crash results in FAILED STATE

Tags: linux, postgresql

I am using `Fedora 15` with `PostgreSQL 9.1.4`. Fedora crashed recently after which:

An attempt to start the PostgreSQL server :

```
service postgresql-9.1 start
```

gives

```
Starting postgresql-9.1 (via systemctl):  Job failed. See system logs and 'systemctl status' for details.
                                                       [FAILED]
```

Although, *the server starts normally when I start the server for the first time after system reboot*.
But, an attempt to use `psql` gives this error :

```
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

`.s.PGSQL.5432` file is not present anywhere on the system.
A `locate .s.PGSQL.5432` outputs nothing.

---

The system log has this :

```
Aug 14 17:31:58 localhost systemd[1]: postgresql-9.1.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Aug 14 17:31:58 localhost systemd[1]: Unit postgresql-9.1.service entered failed state.
```

---

A

```
systemctl status postgresql-9.1.service
```

gives

```
postgresql-9.1.service - SYSV: PostgreSQL database server.
          Loaded: loaded (/etc/rc.d/init.d/postgresql-9.1)
      Active: failed since Tue, 14 Aug 2012 17:31:58 +0530; 58s ago
     Process: 2811 ExecStop=/etc/rc.d/init.d/postgresql-9.1 stop (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
     Process: 12423 ExecStart=/etc/rc.d/init.d/postgresql-9.1 start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
    Main PID: 2551 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
      CGroup: name=systemd:/system/postgresql-9.1.service
```

---

I had not changed the default setting of fsync so I am guessing, it was set to `on`. I am on a HDD. The HDD crashed.

#### HDD crash

The HDD crash resulted in running a manual `fsck` on a prompt and not gui based. With it repairing gazillion inodes etc.. After which I restarted the system with a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd>.

PostgreSQL's log has this:

```
LOG:  database system was interrupted; last known up at 2012-08-14 17:31:57 IST
LOG:  database system was not properly shut down; automatic recovery in progress
LOG:  record with zero length at 0/41A4E58
LOG:  redo is not required
FATAL:  could not access status of transaction 1
DETAIL:  Could not open file "pg_multixact/offsets/0000": No such file or directory.
LOG:  startup process (PID 13016) exited with exit code 1
LOG:  aborting startup due to startup process failure
```

---

## Update

Trying to start the server after taking a file system level copy of the `/var/lib/pgsql` directory, and running `./pg_resetxlog -f /var/lib/pgsql/9.1/data/` with the result `xlog -f /var/lib/pgsql/9.1/data/` still yields in :

```
LOG:  database system was interrupted; last known up at 2012-08-14 18:46:36 IST
LOG:  database system was not properly shut down; automatic recovery in progress
LOG:  record with zero length at 0/6000078
LOG:  redo is not required
FATAL:  could not access status of transaction 1
DETAIL:  Could not open file "pg_multixact/offsets/0000": No such file or directory.
LOG:  startup process (PID 13766) exited with exit code 1
LOG:  aborting startup due to startup process failure
```

Comment: And the Postgres' log?

Comment: @MilenA.Radev Have updated the question with postgres' log..

Comment: `pg_resetxlog` didn't do any good, so you're into fun territory. Do you have a backup of this database from before the crash?

Comment: @CraigRinger Yes I do have a back-up. I actually am enjoying this ride.

Comment: @ThinkingMonkey Awesome! You're one of a select few with good backups :-) . Honestly, it's likely your DB is repairable, but since your file system corruption destroyed important files you'll probably need someone who knows Pg's guts really well to spend some time getting your data out. Services are available here: postgresql.org/support/professional_support . Maybe if you could come up with some dummy content for `pg_multixact/offsets/0000` that Pg would accept...

Comment: @CraigRinger Will give it a try(the dummy data). Thanks for all the help :).

Comment: Could also try `sudo -u postgres postgres --single -D /var/lib/pgsql/data postgres` ... though I don't rate the chances.

Comment: @CraigRinger trying it now..

Comment: @CraigRinger what is the above supposed to do?

Comment: @ThinkingMonkey Starts a PostgreSQL backend in single-user standalone mode. If it runs, you should get a `backend> ` sql prompt. It's possible to do limited recovery and repair. If it can start with the `postgres` database (last argument) try it again with your database of interest, see if you can `select` anything out of any tables.

Comment: @CraigRinger no luck. Let me give it a proper try again.

Comment: Moved discussion to chat, see http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15340/discussion-between-thinkingmonkey-and-craig-ringer

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The real answer will be in the PostgreSQL logs, in `/var/lib/pgsql/data/pg_log`.

However, before you take any action: **It is vital that you take a file system level copy of your database before attempting repair  if any of your data is valuable to you**. See http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Corruption . You must copy the whole data directory. On Fedora that's `/var/lib/pgsql/data` by default, but verify that's correct for your install.

Based on the logs you've posted you certainly have some degree of database corruption. The storage that the database is on (the hard drive or file system) is most likely damaged. Take a copy NOW, and *put it on a different hard drive or system*.

Only once you have made a full file-system level copy of your data directory, try using [pg_resetxlog](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/interactive/app-pgresetxlog.html) to clear the damaged transaction logs and start your database. Even if it starts it is highly likely to be corrupt; you should `pg_dump` it then re-`initdb` it and restore the dump to the fresh instance.

If you still can't start it after a `pg_resetxlog` then post an updated log of the startup attempt after resetxlog. It's possible you'll need to start Pg in stand-alone mode with:

```
sudo -u postgres postgres --single -D /var/lib/pgsql/data -P -f i postgres
```

If that works, giving you a `backend>` prompt, try again after replacing the last "postgres" with the name of the DB you want to connect to. You should be able to `SELECT`, `COPY` data from tables, etc.

If that *doesn't* work, ie you can't start a standalone backend, then it's probably time to restore from backups - since you're sensible enough to have them. If anyone else reading this is in the same position, [contact an experienced PostgreSQL consultant](http://www.postgresql.org/support/professional_support/) to see if they can recover data from your database. Be prepared to pay for their time and expertise.

### Your file system is probably damaged

The severity of the damage to the PostgreSQL install suggests that your whole file system is probably damaged. You may wish to consider restoring the whole system from a backup or reinstalling it.

I would not trust this file system, `fsck` or no `fsck`.

### SMART-test your drive

I also recommend that you run a `SMART` check on your hard drive with `smartctl` from smartmontools; assuming it's `/dev/hda` that'd be `smartctl -d ata -a /dev/sda | less` . Look for a failed health test, `uncorrectable_sectors`, a high read error rate, a reallocated_sector_count of more than 2 or 3, or a non-zero current_pending_sector. Run `smartctl -d ata -t long /dev/sda` to execute a non-destructive self test on your HDD; it won't interrupt normal functioning of the system. When the estimated time has elapsed run `smartctl -d ata /dev/sda` again and look at the self test log to see if it passed.

If anything looks less than perfect, replace the drive.

In future, consider automating this testing via `smartd` for early warning of drive failures.

(Content in this post was obsoleted by updates to the question. If you're troubleshooting a similar problem, look at this answer's edit history).

Comment: I have added postgres' log in the question. I had not changed the default setting of `fsync` so I am guessing, it was set to `on`. I am on a HDD. Yes, the HDD crashed. I have not run out of disk space. No memory error/overheat/tripped over cable/kerpanic.

Comment: @ThinkingMonkey What kind of "HDD crash"? Did you have to do data recovery on the hard drive to copy the files to a new drive? Did you have to run `fsck` and do file system repairs? Details, please. Write the story of your crash.

Comment: The HDD crash resulted in running a manual `fsck` for . With it repairing gazillion inodes etc.. After which the system restarted.
_Have updated the above in the question as well._

Comment: @ThinkingMonkey OK, answer updated. TL;DR: *make a complete file system level copy of /var/lib/pgsql* then run `pg_resetxlog`

Comment: thanks.. onto the copy & resetxlog. will be back with the results soon.

Comment: Have updated the question with details after _make a complete file system level copy of /var/lib/pgsql then running `pg_resetxlog`_ . Server still does not start.