# PostgreSQL crash recovery

Tags: postgresql

We are planning to use PostgreSQL in our application but are concerned about crash-safety and recovery.

I can't find any database crash recovery method or process in PostgreSQL. I know there must be something in PostgreSQL.

Advice? So if anyone can help me out to find  this then that would be great.

Comment: Crash recovery means if my database crashes due to some reasons then is there any possibility in postgressql that I can recover my data.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

### Crash Safety

PostgreSQL is crash-safe within certain limits. It *guarantees* to *always* preserve committed data if the database system crashes or the host it's on reboots/loses power/crashes unexpectedly. That's what the `D` in [`ACID`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) means - atomicity, consistency, isolation, durability.

The critical feature in PostgreSQL's crash safety is the [write-ahead log (WAL)](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/wal.html). The documentation explains it much better than I ever could.

This crash safety is *not a substitute for good backups*.

- PostgreSQL cannot protect you against file system corruption or hard drive failure. The storage system it uses needs to be reliable.
- Hard drives and SSDs *will* fail, so RAID is necessary but not sufficient for protection. You need backups and/or replication to protect against multi-drive failures, file system corruption, etc.
- There are certain settings documented in PostgreSQL that weaken the crash-safety guarantees it makes. For example, if you set `fsync=off` you give PostgreSQL permission to destroy your data if it crashes in exchange for going a bit faster.
- PostgreSQL guarantees that it will *not* save uncommitted data, it will be lost if the system crashes before a transaction `COMMIT`s. Statements not surrounded by `BEGIN` and `COMMIT` for this purpose commit when the statement returns.

There's more, but the short version is that Pg is crash-safe and durable, but you still need to look after the other layers in your infrastructure, which is why you need:

### Backups

Don't just do a weekly `pg_dump` where you overwrite the same dump file over and over, that'll end in tears. Use more than one backup strategy, and keep historical backups not just a most recent backup.

For example, I keep both [dumps](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/backup-dump.html) and a [continuous archiving/PITR replica](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/continuous-archiving.html). I keep daily `pg_dump`s for a week, then weekly dumps for a month and monthly dumps for a year to give me some timeline protection. For the PITR setup I refresh from a base backup every week; it's mostly there to give me the ability to recover to the nearest 5-minutes from any failure or catastrophic mistake. Nightly dumps won't help me recover the last 23 hours of data when I accidentally drop a table; PITR will.

There's lots more here:

- [Pg manual - backup and restore](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/backup.html)
- [Pg manual - streaming replication](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/warm-standby.html#STREAMING-REPLICATION)
- [Pg manual - high availability](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/high-availability.html)
- [Pg wiki - Backup category](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Category:Backup)
- [Pg wiki - high availability](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/High_Availability)

Don't be one of the people who turns up on the Pg list saying "my hard drive crashed, how can I recover my database?". Be like [this guy](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/22486/starting-postgresql-server-after-a-hdd-crash-results-in-failed-state/22487#22487), who asked the question for fun because he had backups but was curious if his DB could be recovered. (Answer: probably not).

### Repair or recovery of corrupt databases

**If you're reading this because you found it in a search and you suspect you have a corrupt Pg database, read [this](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Corruption) before attempting *any* repair**.

If by *crash recovery* you mean a repair tool to fix a damaged database, no, there isn't anything much. `pg_resetxlog` may save you from corrupt/lost transaction logs, but will probably corrupt your database in the process, so you usually need to dump and reload afterwards. There isn't any kind of `fsck` tool, nor is there anything like `myisamchk` because unlike MyISAM, Pg's tables are designed not to get corrupted as a routine part of normal operation. It'd actually be quite nice to have some sort of `pg_dbcheck`, but it would probably not be able to tell you much more than "Yup, there's some corruption here, go find a backup".

The database just doesn't get damaged in the first place unless:

- The underlying hardware fails
- The OS or file system has a bug
- PostgreSQL has a bug
- PostgreSQL is explicitly configured not to be durable
- The user did something silly like went around deleting things from the database directory

In all of these cases automated repair would be impractical anyway.

Keep good backups of *any* database, not just Pg. Don't rely on being able to repair corruption, because you probably won't be able to.

Answer (score 5):

It sounds you are looking for Point In Time Recovery: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/continuous-archiving.html

The chapter about high availability might also be interesting for you: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/high-availability.html